Synapse started fail with Postgres error in configuration: No database config provided
I am trying to setup synapse in my vps Ubuntu 20.04, synapse start ok with default sqlite3. But when I switch to postgres, it started fail with log, could you please help why I missing database config?
May 22 03:08:54 example.com matrix-synapse[1265]: Error in configuration:
May 22 03:08:54 example.com matrix-synapse[1265]:   No database config provided
May 22 03:08:54 example.com systemd[1]: matrix-synapse.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
I installed postgres
apt install libpq5 postgresql -y
su - postgres
createuser --pwprompt synapse
createdb --encoding=UTF8 --locale=C --template=template0 --owner=synapse synapse
check it with qspl /l, database synapse was created.
postgres=# \l
List of databases
Name      |       Owner       | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
----------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
matrix_synapse | matrix_synapse_rw | UTF8     | C           | C           |
postgres       | postgres          | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
synapse        | synapse           | UTF8     | C           | C           |
template0      | postgres          | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
|                   |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
template1      | postgres          | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
|                   |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
enable password authentication to synapse database.
cat /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
host    synapse         synapse         ::1/128                 md5
check postgresql ok
~# ps -ef|grep postgresql
postgres     884       1  0 03:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
The I modify homeserver.yaml to postgres.
database:
 name: psycopg2
 args:
  user: synapse
  password: synapse
  database: synapse
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  cp_min: 5
  cp_max: 10
I tried the other user and database matrix_synapse, but still the same error. If I switch back to sqlite3, it started normally.
